# "New folder" Keyboard shortcut in windows xp sp3?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts

well in windows 7 you can use this combination to make a new folder : shift+Ctrl+N
is there such combination in windows xp sp3 to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no native way of doing this in XP. The closest you can get is to type:

> <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>

while keeping <kbd>Alt</kbd> key pressed down. This executes the **File > New > Folder..** sequence from the menu.

Other than that it's installing a third party program. bxNewFolder seems to be mentioned in a few post. [Here](http://www.tothepc.com/archives/create-new-folder-with-keyboard-shortcut-hotkey-in-windows-xp/) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Best one I found (even better than Baxbex) is [mdAxel 1.0 Beta](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/mdAxel-Download-134898.html). The name is deceiving. It is a small footprint, non-installing "New Folder" hotkey .exe app that you insert in your Program Files folder. In Program Files, I named the folder "New Folder Hotkey" and pasted this .exe app in it. Then I double-clicked on it and it started up and the icon appeared in my System Tray in the Task Bar. I right clicked on that System Tray icon and selected "Settings". I chose to have it start up with Windows, and I chose my own hotkey combo. I could even provide a default "New Folder" entry. It's free and works super well. Best one yet!

BaxBex is if you want to have a new folder icon in your Explorer toolbar, but the downside is if you are installing a new theme with the Uxepatcher and use YZ Toolbar (for example) then the Baxbex new folder icon cannot be modified to match your new icons. BUt if you are sticking with your XP default icons then that is a good mate to this hotkey app.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Menu</kbd> -> <kbd>W</kbd> -> <kbd>F</kbd> will open the right-click menu, select New then select Folder.

Not quite what you're after as it's not a single combination, but might be sufficent for you.