# Shortcut for New Folder for windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to create a new folder using just the keyboard in Windows XP.

I am looking for the Windows XP equivalent for the Windows 7 key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.

Could someone tell me what this combination or shortcut is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The closest you can get is to type: `F, W, F` while keeping `Alt` pressed down." (While in Windows Explorer)

Duplicate of ["New folder" Keyboard shortcut in windows xp sp3?](https://superuser.com/questions/188819/new-folder-keyboard-shortcut-in-windows-xp-sp3)

Comment: Can we have some registry tweak, to some shortcut??

Comment: The safest way, in my mind, to automate a process in Windows is with AutoHotKey. Looks like this has already been worked out: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/18100-create-new-folder-keyboard-shortcut/